# How would I use jquery ajaxstart and ajaxstop with $.post?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Basically I want to show a loading gif...

here's the code I'm using:

```
$("#mail-change input[type=submit]").click(function(event){

$.post('user_settings.php', $("#mail-change").serialize(), function(res) {

$(res).insertBefore(".grey");

}, 'html')

});
```

Answer (score 15):

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

EDIT:

```
$("#mail-change input[type=submit]").click(function(event){
    $("#loading").show()
    $.post('user_settings.php', $("#mail-change").serialize(), function(res) {
        $(res).insertBefore(".grey");
        $("#loading").hide();
    }, 'html');
});
```

or:

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'user_settings.php',
   data: $("#mail-change").serialize(),
   beforeSend: function(){
     $("#loading").show();
   },
   complete: function(){
     $("#loading").hide();
   },
   success: function(res) {
     $(res).insertBefore(".grey");
   }
 });
```

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/
- http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/
- http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events
- http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Problem is that I have multiple forms with $.post requests on the page.... This code would get triggered by any one of the $.post requests

Comment: @pete - in that case, I would suggest revealing the loading indicator right before the `$.post` and hiding it again within the success callback. Please see my edit.

Comment: @pete - one other thing, you can use `$.ajax`'s `beforeSend` and `complete` callbacks too. I've just edited again.