# adding preloader to div tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, preloader

we have an ajax script that gets a word and loads some related data into a div tag.

it works fine but we want to add preloader (without jQuery) to div tag, we tried [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/) but it works only for whole page, this is what we did: (Summarized)

```
<head>
<script src="spin.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="data">

 //data loads here

 </div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var opts = {
  lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 7, // The length of each line
  width: 4, // The line thickness
  radius: 28, // The radius of the inner circle
  rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
  color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
  speed: 1, // Rounds per second
  trail: 92, // Afterglow percentage
  shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
  hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
  className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
  left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
};
var target = document.getElementById('data');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
</script>


</body>
```

what is wrong? 
and any other (and better) solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` `div` has full width and `spin.js` will place the image at the center of the element both vertically and horizontally thats why you are seeing this on a full screen based.

For e.g.

```
<head>
    <script src="spin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="data" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left;">
        <!-- Data Loads Here-->
    </div>
    <div id="NoData" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left;">
        Hello Hi Bye
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var opts = {
            lines : 13, // The number of lines to draw
            length : 7, // The length of each line
            width : 4, // The line thickness
            radius : 28, // The radius of the inner circle
            rotate : 0, // The rotation offset
            color : '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
            speed : 1, // Rounds per second
            trail : 92, // Afterglow percentage
            shadow : false, // Whether to render a shadow
            hwaccel : false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            className : 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
            zIndex : 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
            top : 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
            left : 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
        };
        var target = document.getElementById('data');
        var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: but: 1 - spining works until whole page load (pics, logoes, etc) 2 - when testing ajax it loads data without any loading splash.

Comment: how are you initializing your spin on ajax start ?

Comment: seems its point.. how to do this? (i'm noob on ajax/loader handling)

Comment: can you use jQuery ajaxStart, ajaxStop ?

Comment: i think using jQuery is much easier.. but it needs to load jquery lib first. (if u think there is not any other way i'll test it)

i need to call spin when ajax form submitted?

Comment: please <script src="jQuery.js" /> before spin.js it will do, also I noticed on their site they have a jQuery plugin. See this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251379/how-would-i-use-jquery-ajaxstart-and-ajaxstop-with-post) how to use ajaxStart, ajaxStop. And yes if you use jQuery it is much easier then plain javascript