# jQuery blockUI() is NOT working when invoked on beforeSend

Tags: jquery, ajax

Not sure what is the problem with below code, somehow i am not able to get blockUI() working.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "before",     
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "text",
    async : true,
    data : formData,
    beforeSend : function() { $.blockUI({ message: 'OK' });   }, 
    success : function(response) {
            $.unblockUI();
            alert("Congrats! Success!");
            var successUrl = "after";   
            window.location.href = successUrl;
            return false;
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $.unblockUI();  
        alert("Oops ! Error occurred !");
    }
});// End of ajax
```

I tried - async : false as well as true.

Comment: did you try logging into console in beforeSend? Does it fire?

Comment: yeah, i checked and it does not fire, it is directly going for error and not even processing my ajax call. If I remove beforeSend, ajax call works perfectly alright.

Comment: Why not use ajaxStart and stop to deal this? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251379/how-would-i-use-jquery-ajaxstart-and-ajaxstop-with-post

Comment: More help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046387/jquery-ajax-beforesend

Comment: @Jagdish okay, what error does it throw?

Comment: @Rahul, exception I am getting is "TypeError: $.blockUI is not a function" and i get this error @ -  

beforeSend : function() { $.blockUI({ message: 'OK' });   },

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.8.2

Comment: are you sure blockUI JS is being loaded properly after jQuery?

Comment: nah, i do not see blockUI.js loaded under Scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the discussion we had in comments above, You don't have blockUI script loaded in HTML page..

Download it from here : http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js

and include it in script tag..

Message to others :

If you have jQuery 1.9+ and BlockUI plugin, make sure you use jquery-migrate plugin since jquery browser api is deprecated in version 1.9+..

Hope that solves the issue.